# GL SE logo and 'beta' status

Tags: support, design

Is it true that GL SE can't have its logo as long as it has 'beta' status?

*(I know that there were several related questions before, but none of them are as specific as this question, and some of them are obviously obsolete)*

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Gardening & Landscaping design and logo - Information gathering](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/37696) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982/37696)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting a custom design is one of the perks of site graduation. It used to be that getting the design happened at the same time as graduation, but Stack Exchange changed that policy some time ago: see [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) and other questions about ["design-independent graduation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=design%20independent%20graduation%20is%3Aq) on [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for more information.

So, yes, it's true that this site won't get a design until after graduation. It might be a long time after graduation too. As an example, [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) graduated in September 2016 and doesn't have a design yet.

Comment: Thanks Niall C.! I saw that the question had been raised in a recent discussion in the chat room. I spent some time wandering through SE meta posts in order to help, but I kept going around in circles!  I appreciate your choosing the right ones and offering them here for education!

Comment: And now both sites are getting custom themes... :)

Answer (score 5):

We have some news there. There is some discussion on SE, and we are also nominated on such proposal: [Let's break up with "Graduation" and remove a bunch of "Beta" labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/lets-break-up-with-graduation-and-remove-a-bunch-of-beta-labels).

In short: maybe stable and long live beta sites will have an upgrade (from beta), but not yet with full perks (custom design/logo).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's an interesting post. I went there and posted an answer. I hope it doesn't bring me the label of "lazy user who wants to graduate without working hard enough".